# PIP won't intall scriptine, any version

Tags: python-2.7, installation, pip, scriptine

pip installed other libraries before and after I encountered this problem, so I'm really confused.

I couldn't install the desired version (scriptine>=0.2.1) from a requirements.txt for a package I'm using (pydial) so I cycled through trying to directly download different versions and an unspecified version. I've used the --no-cache-dir command to try installing without using the cached tar. The last run I have cycled through downloading every version and gave the message below except swap the scriptine version number and it tried them all and repeated the message for each version.

I'm trying to install scriptine to work with PyDial, which uses python 2.7.  I'm installing from the command line, not a space I'm comfortable in, but have solved all minor past problems without any difficulty.

Any help?

> Downloading scriptine-0.1.0.tar.gz (28 kB)
> Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>
> `command: 'C:\Users\trigg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\trigg\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ylyn0kwd\\scriptine_2a0ef30b1e904e53a4408c746494d3d9\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\trigg\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ylyn0kwd\\scriptine_2a0ef30b1e904e53a4408c746494d3d9\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\trigg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-l8xqqciu' cwd: C:\Users\trigg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ylyn0kwd\scriptine_2a0ef30b1e904e53a4408c746494d3d9\ Complete output (10 lines):   Traceback (most recent call last):    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>    File "C:\Users\trigg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ylyn0kwd\scriptine_2a0ef30b1e904e53a4408c746494d3d9\setup.py", line 1, in <module> import scriptine    File "C:\Users\trigg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ylyn0kwd\scriptine_2a0ef30b1e904e53a4408c746494d3d9\scriptine\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>       from scriptine._path import path    File "C:\Users\trigg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ylyn0kwd\scriptine_2a0ef30b1e904e53a4408c746494d3d9\scriptine\_path.py", line 69 True, False = 1, 0 ^   SyntaxError: cannot assign to True`
>
> ---
>
> WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0e/8e/d1084f6521208a2a2a4b60c9b46f16bb704f621ea118e9d22fccb3a289e9/scriptine-0.1.0.tar.gz#sha256=95f49125a9b5cf65bb54f7f0075ee820830a84eb199e40ef783cf4e5d65b52cc (from https://pypi.org/simple/scriptine/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scriptine (from versions: 0.1.0, 0.2.0a1, 0.2.0a2, 0.2.0a3, 0.2.0a4, 0.2.0, 0.2.1)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for scriptine
>
> WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip
> (c:\users\trigg\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages)
> WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip
> (c:\users\trigg\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
True, False = 1, 0
^   SyntaxError: cannot assign to True
```

In Python 3 `True` and `False` became keywords, assigning to them is an error.

The code in question is obviously for Python 2. Version 0.2.1 was released in 2015 and is no longer updated. The package seems to be outdated and abandoned. Forget about it, [find](https://pypi.org/search/?q=shell+scripts) something to replace it

Comment: Rats! I had the p2 version and the p3 version downloaded, I've obviously been rerunning the p2 version over and over. Thank you!